# css - transform: translateX(-200%) created horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar, css-transforms

I have created animation for element in the page to slide in from the left, so it's starting point is

```
transform: translateX(-200%)
```

but when the page loads it has a scrollbar.
I'm using Chrome. it happens also in FF.
I'm also getting vertical scrollbar for

```
transform: translateY(200%)
```

I tried using

```
body, html{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

which seems to make the scrollbars disappear, but then the animation also doesn't work, I'm getting empty window until the animation ends.
The question is how can I use the animation with same parameters but without the scrollbar (horizontal and vertical).

more code:

```
.text {
   transform: translateX(-200%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-200%);
   animation: slide-in-fleft 1s forwards;
  -webkit-animation: slide-in-fleft 1s forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@keyframes slide-in-fleft {
  100% { transform: translateX(0%); }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style> 
                div {
                    width: 100px;
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: red;
                    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                    animation-name: example;
                    animation-duration: 2s;
                    transform: translateX(200%);
                 }

                    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
                 @-webkit-keyframes example {
                    from {transform: translateX(-200%);}
                    to {transform: translateX(200%);}
                 }

                    /* Standard syntax */
                 @keyframes example {
                    from {transform: translateX(-200%);}
                    to {transform: translateX(200%);}
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>

            <div></div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

When an animation is finished, it changes back to its original style

Comment: it doesn't really answer the question. Thanks.